# ZF2: Call redirect() url | trigger GET from a post action

Tags: php, post, redirect, header, zend-framework2

I have a simple post which looks like

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/album/createAlbum.html',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: postData,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Successfully saved album");
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("FAILED to save album");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and a simple action which looks like

```
public function createAlbumAction()
{
    $request    = $this->getRequest();
    $response   = $this->getResponse();

    $album     = $request->getPost('album');

    //First check to see if the user already has that album
    $albumObject = $this->_dataService->getAlbum($userID, $album);

    if ($albumObject){
       //This is the issue
        $this->redirect()->toRoute('albumModule', array('controller' => 'album', 'action' => 'edit'));
    } else {
        $albumObject    = $this->_dataService->createAlbum($userID, $album);
    }


    $messages = array();
    if (!empty($messages)){
        $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode($messages));
    } else {
        $response->setContent(\Zend\Json\Json::encode(array('albumID' => $albumObject->getAlbumID())));
    }
    return $response;
}
```

The issue I'm having is on the `redirect()`, I know that the redirect will send me to that route, but I need to tell the browser to `GET` that route. I can't figure out how to do this from a `POST`. I read something about setting the header to 303 so that the browser knows to do redirect, but I wouldn't know how to return that in my JSON response.

Even when I try to do `header:("Location: " ...)` that won't tell the browser to GET the url.

Comment: If you want to redirect user to another page you probably need to do with Java Script. So, return some status in Ajax response, and do redirect in JS.

Comment: @tasmaniski k, I can do that. Just wish there was some simple way to do it from the server :(

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up going with this

On the ajax call

```
error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("FAILED to save album");

        //The Album already exists, so redirect to it
        window.location = request.getResponseHeader('redirectURL');
        return false;
      },
```

On the ZF2 Action

```
$response->setStatusCode(Response::STATUS_CODE_301)->getHeaders()
         ->addHeaders(array('redirectURL' => $this->url()->fromRoute('albumModule', array('controller' => 'album', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => $albumObject->getAlbumID()))));
return $response;
```